# Rotate count out of Range error

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

I am new to assembly language programming.
Can anyone figure out where I am going wrong?
The error while assembling is

> Rotate count out of Range error
>   Error is at line: rol bl, 04

This is my code:

```
disp macro var
    lea dx, var
    mov ah, 09H
    int 21H
endm

ending macro
    mov ah, 4cH
    int 21H
endm

.model small
.stack 100H
.data
        msg1 db 10, 13, "_____STRING OPERATION_____$"
        msg2 db 10, 13, "1.Length", 10, 13, "2.Reverse $"
        msg3 db 10, 13, "3.Exit", 10, 13, "--->$"
        error db 10, 13, "Enter a valid choice ",10, 13, "$"
        msg4 db 10, 13, "Enter the string: $"
        msg5 db 10, 13, "Length of the string: $"
        msg6 db 10, 13, "Reversed String: $"
        choice db ?
        str1 db 20, ?, 20 dup(0)
.code
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax

menu:   disp msg1
        disp msg2
        disp msg3

        mov ah, 01H
        int 21H
        mov choice, al

        cmp choice, 31H
        je str_len
        cmp choice, 32H
        je Reverse
        cmp choice, 33H
        je Exit
        disp error
        jmp menu

str_len:disp msg4
        mov ah, 0aH
        lea dx, str1
        int 21H

        disp msg5

        lea si, str1[1]
        mov bl, [si]
        mov cl, 02
back:   rol bl, 04
        mov dl, bl

        mov ah, 02H
        int 21H
        loop back

        ending

Reverse:

Exit:   ending

end
```

Comment: Try to add `.386` at the start, if you don't need to stay on 8086. 8086 supports only `,1` or `,cl` operands, not `,imm8` form.

Comment: He does specify 8086 as a tag...

Comment: after using .386, some warning popped up like "Assuming segment is 32 bit" but it is going into infinite loop with garbage value printed

Comment: @DavidHoelzer nope, that was added by zx485. @OP: .386C then for some old tasm maybe? or .286 only... or just rewrite it with 4x `,1`. (or rewrite it with `,cl` and use some other register for loop counter, for example `di` looks to be spare).

Comment: The `.386` needs probably another directive line: `option  segment:use16` (from this example: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH06/CH06-6.html )

Comment: @Ped7g Ah, my mistake.  I thought it was there originally.

Comment: @Ped7g : Might not even need `.386`. `.186` should suffice since that is when the multi bit shift/rotate instructions with immediate were introduced. An interesting foot note is that on some versions of Turbo Assembler (At least with 3.0+) if you use default (`.8086`) `rol bl, 04` is converted into 4 `rol bl, 1` instructions. With `.186` (or higher) it will generate the instruction with an immediate.

Comment: Decided to do an experiment. I couldn't get this error with TASM 3.0, as it does conversion to multiple ROL instructions when 8086 is being emitted and an immediate shift count operand is used. Version 2.0 of TASM does in fact generate `Rotate count out of Range error` by default (8086 mode). Using `.186` does work, but then of course your code won't wok on a 8086/8088 based processor (this may or not be an issue)

Answer (score 4):

The `ROR` and `ROL` instructions in the 8086 instruction set take either an immediate value of 1 or a count stored in `CL`.  To rotate 4 bits, you would need to do this:

```
 MOV  CL, 4
 ROR  BL, CL
```

Comment: i am not getting the desired result ( i.e length ,it is printing some special character). Is CL not used for keeping the count?

Comment: @ChanchalRoshan yes, `cl` is dedicated for count as well as for > 1 rotations in an 8086. So you'll need to save `cl` off each time through the loop (copy to another register and back, for example) for one of the purposes. Or, just do 4 separate `rol bl, 1` instructions in a row, which may be more efficient due to the low count (4) of iterations you need.

Comment: @ChanchalRoshan you also need to convert your number to ASCII before printing.

Answer (score 0):

Real mode has a lot more limitations than protected mode about which registers do what and which instructions are valid.  If you're used to programming in protected mode and long mode you should probably become familiar with these restrictions.

Another really commonly encountered restriction is that only the registers `BX` and `BP` are valid as base address offsets; the instruction `00 00` (`add byte ptr [eax], al`) in protected mode becomes `add [bx+si], al` in real mode, for example.

If the amount you are rotating by is not exactly 1, you need to put the count in `CL` and use that as the second operand for the `ro[l|r]` instruction -  immediate values other than 1 are not valid.

Comment: Starting with the 80186/80188 16-bit instructions included shift and rotate instructions (in real mode)  with an immediate operand. TASM 2.0 will generate the error in the OP's question, but TASM 3.0 will convert `rol bl, 04` to 4 separate and consecutive  `rol bl, 1` instructions.